# running tests in a maven multi module project

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, junit

I have a maven multi project with this pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>booking</groupId>
    <artifactId>booking</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <!-- sub modules -->
    <modules>
        <module>b1</module>
        <module>b5</module>
        <module>l1</module>
        <module>l20</module>
    </modules>


</project>
```

[image]

but when I run the tests in the root maven I got this result: `No tests to run.`

```
public class CalculationFunctionImplTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {

        CalculationFunctionImpl calculationFunctionImpl = new CalculationFunctionImpl ("time");
        System.out.println(calculationFunctionImpl.calculate());


    }

}
```

Comment: Please show us the command you ran and the command line output.

Comment: mvn test from terminal

Comment: How are your tests class named? And where are they located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main module is of packaging POM (as it should be), but this means that tests are not run in the build lifecycle of the main project.

It is probably best to move the tests to a module.

Comment: I took this as an example and it works with the same approach https://github.com/mesche/maven-multi-project-example